# Export logic analyzer data to protocol analyzer

Tags: hardware, usb, wireshark

Probably I'm little ot but I'm unsure where to ask this.
Is there any easy (already working) way to export my logic analyzer data (vcd format) to a protocol analyzer like Wireshark? I'm analyzing an USB stream.

Comment: Have you tried sigrok program (https://sigrok.org)? It has support for vcd format and is able to decode USB protocol.

Comment: Nope, I'll give it a try! Thanks

Comment: It's a bit unhandly, as my native logic analyzer program. I would like to use something more protocol oriented like Wireshark.

Comment: As far as I remember there is pulseview program that allows to load vcd format and attach protocol decoders on top. Would you mind sharing example vcd file?

Comment: It has been my first try, It's very nice looking program, but I need a tool to analyze protocol flow... and list / filter them so I can get the big picture. Scroll ahead and back through packetes with pulseview is a pain.